# canvas.toDataURL Alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, web

I'm trying to convert an the contents of an HTML5 canvas to a png image.

Problem is that the canvas contains an image that isn't hosted locally so I get the security error.

I don't have the option to host the image locally, is there any other way to capture what is inside the canvas element?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with the image?

Comment: Allow the user to download it, eventually have the ability to share it via twitter+facebook..but that's a whole other monster.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can make your image resource CORS friendly, then no.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CORS_Enabled_Image#What_is_a_.22tainted.22_canvas.3F

> Although you can use images without CORS approval in your canvas,
>   doing so taints the canvas. Once a canvas has been tainted, you can no
>   longer pull data back out of the canvas. For example, you can no
>   longer use the canvas toBlob(), toDataURL(), or getImageData()
>   methods; doing so will throw a security error.

Edit: Of course, if you aren't limited to pure HTML5 methods, there are some Flash/Crossdomain.xml tricks you could use, but that still assumes you have some control over the server which serves the images.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using jQuery this plugin my do the trick.

http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/

Answer (score 0):

Guess there is no way around that on the client-side otherwise what would be the point of blocking `toDataURL` anyway right?

Maybe you could have a server side script forwarding external images to the client so the browser won't know it's from another domain. (Not that it need to anyway since you can't use the browser's credentials from the server side)

Just send the image url as a get parameter, have the content-type header modified according to the image file, of course, and just spread all those bytes on the response content.